# How can I delete all duplicates keeping only 4 duplicates of that row?

Tags: mysql, duplicates

Below is the screenshot of having multiple versions of track with track_id=5. I want to retain 4 and remove all in Mysql.

[image]

The above screenshot shows many duplicate rows. Seeing track_id and artist_id as duplicate I want to keep 4 duplicates and to remove other duplicate rows for that record.

Comment: Please view screenshot for more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this validation while saving records like below code:

```
$artist_q1 = $this->DbYtVideoVersions->find()->where(['track_name'=>$artist->track_match, 'artist_name'=>$artist->artist_match]);
                                                if($artist_q1->count()<4){
                                                $playlist_en = $this->DbYtVideoVersions->newEntity();  
                                                $this->DbYtVideoVersions->patchEntity($playlist_en, $trackData);
                                                $this->DbYtVideoVersions->save($playlist_en);
                                                }
```

Comment: pleasure is all mine :)